# Uncorrelated, Non Independent Random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I don't understand the parts highlighted in green. I understand that the supports imply that  X and Y are not independent but not how the graph shows this  graph. I'm a bit confused by all aspects of the graph to be frank.

$Y=X^2 + Z$ to avoid any confusion.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without getting too deep into the mathematical definitions, consider the following
informal argument.

The notion of *independence* of two random random variables is intended to
capture the intuitive meaning of independence: given the value of one of
the random variables, you do not know anything more about the other than
you did before, that is, whatever value $X$ might take on does not influence
the value of $Y$. So, in your case of $Y = X^2+Z$, we know that $X^2$ has value
in $[0,1)$ while $Z$ has value in $(0,0.1)$. Thus, the value of $Y$ can be anywhere
in $[0, 1.1)$; indeed, if you had never heard of $X$ and $Z$ but were merely
observing $Y$, that would your conclusion: $Y$ takes on values in $[0,1.1)$.

But now suppose that you know that $X$ had value $0.5$. Then, from the
knowledge that $Y = X^2 + Z$, that $Y$ *must* have value in $(0.25,0.35)$.
Thus knowing the value of $X$ tells you *something* that you did not
know before about $Y$. No longer can $Y$ range from $0$ to $1.1$; it must
necessarily be restricted to the picayune range $(0.25,0.35)$.  Hence,
$X$ and $Y$ are *not independent.*

Since informal arguments are often eschewed in favor of analytical
verifications, here is a simple test for *dependence* that requires
only some elementary notions from geometry.  If the joint
distribution of $(X,Y)$ does *not* have support that is a
rectangle with sides parallel to the axes, then the random variables
are *dependent.* (More knowledgeable folks: please hold your fire, I am
trying to keep it as simple as possible to get the essential point across).
In your example, the banana-shaped hand-drawn figure cannot be
construed to be a rectangle, and so this **eyeball** test says that
$X$ and $Y$ are *dependent.* In particular, laboriously calculation of
$f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ and then checking whether it is true that
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ is totally unnecessary.
That $(X,Y)$ is *uniformly distributed*
on this region is true in your example, but not relevant to the
issue of independence which can be answered in the negative simply
by looking at the banana.

> Don't apply this argument in the opposite direction: the support being
> a rectangle does *not* prove independence; it merely suggests that
> it *might* be true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables,
> but to prove that they *are* indeed independent requires more work.

Answer (score 0):

The region has four boundaries: two parabolas (one is 0.1 higher than the other), and two vertical line segments on the left and right sides.  Choosing a point uniformly at random in this region is equivalent to choosing $X$ uniformly at random in $[-1,1]$, squaring, then adding a random number chosen uniformly at random in $[0,0.1]$.